# cloning a table from one database to another with same rowid's in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, data-structures

Is there any way to do the following :
I have an empty sqlite database and another sqlite database with one table A. Table A has some records with unpredictable rowid's because of several deletes and inserts in the past )

I like to copy/clone table A to the empty database ( for example with an ATTACH DB and create Table as Select ) . But also I like to preserve the old rowid's of the original Table A, so that in the copied/cloned Table A are the same rowid's for each row.

Is there any way to do that ? ( No backup/rollback tools. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy over the values in the `rowid` columns like those in any other one:

```
INSERT INTO db2.MyTable(rowid, Name, whatever)
SELECT                  rowid, Name, whatever FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that. So easy. Its really possible to insert into rowid. Perfect thank you very much !